# How is http://shell.appspot.com/ executing code online?

Tags: python

I'm building a website which allows you to write python code online just like http://shell.appspot.com/ or http://ideone.com. Can someone please provide me some help how I can achieve this?

Comment: appspot is somewhat of a special case since it's running on a platform that's already designed to allow malicious code. ideone is way more interesting ;)

Comment: When you asked the authors of those sites, what did they say?  They would know better than a bunch of random strangers.

Comment: Ideone is not doubt great api but it introduces time delay which makes interactive use bit slow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you can browse their [source code](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/downloads/detail?name=shell_20091112.tar.gz&can=2&q=). The main file is only 321 lines !

Basically it keeps a separate global dict for each user session, then uses `compile` and `exec` to run the code and return the result.

```
# log and compile the statement up front
try:
  logging.info('Compiling and evaluating:\n%s' % statement)
  compiled = compile(statement, '<string>', 'single')
except:
  self.response.out.write(traceback.format_exc())
  return
```

and

```
  # run!
  old_globals = dict(statement_module.__dict__)
  try:
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    old_stderr = sys.stderr
    try:
      sys.stdout = self.response.out
      sys.stderr = self.response.out
      exec compiled in statement_module.__dict__
    finally:
      sys.stdout = old_stdout
      sys.stderr = old_stderr
  except:
    self.response.out.write(traceback.format_exc())
    return
```

**Edit:** Not using Google App Engine would make things much more complicated.But you can take a look at [pysandbox](https://github.com/haypo/pysandbox)

Comment: Thanks for the replay. Actually I was able to figure it out on my own. But getting the source code has added complete new dimension to thinking

Answer (score 2):

I am new to python but hopefully following links could help you acheive ur goal,
BaseHTTPServer (http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html) library can be used for handling web requests and ipython (http://ipython.org) for executing python commands at the backend.

Comment: Yes, but the problem that you need to protect your server from executed code:)